# calling post method with large data (12K objects)

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am trying to update a dataset to webapi POST method. The call is ok if the `data` is 1K rows  however it is null on `webapi` if sending ~12K rows.

```
public static string Update(string url, object data)
        {
            var client = GetClient();

            //request
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);

            var json = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            // execute the request
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            return response.Content; // raw content as string
        }
```

Any suggestion pls?

Comment: The body size depends upon the web server you are using

Comment: thanks. that worked.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `maxRequestLength` to web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000000" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
```